# Merging a Python script's subprocess' stdout and stderr while keeping them distinguishable

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I would like to direct a python script's subprocess' stdout and stdin into the same file. What I don't know is how to make the lines from the two sources distinguishable? (For example prefix the lines from stderr with an exclamation mark.)

In my particular case there is no need for live monitoring of the subprocess, the executing Python script can wait for the end of its execution.

Comment: What if some of the program's stdout starts with an exclamation point?

Comment: Is it ok to dump all the stdout and then all the stderr to the same file, or do you want them interleaved?

Comment: I would like to have it interleaved.

Comment: That is an awesome question that I'll try to answer! However, _for now_, it looks like it would need some kind of asynchronous output [that `Popen` does not support _yet_](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3145/) so this is a challenging question.

Comment: the answers are related: [Run command and get its stdout, stderr separately in near real time like in a terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31953436/4279)

Answer (score 67):

```
tsk = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

[`subprocess.STDOUT`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STDOUT) is a special flag that tells subprocess to route all stderr output to stdout, thus combining your two streams.

btw, select doesn't have a poll() in windows. subprocess only uses the file handle number, and doesn't call your file output object's write method.

to capture the output, do something like:

```
logfile = open(logfilename, 'w')

while tsk.poll() is None:
    line = tsk.stdout.readline()
    logfile.write(line)
```

Comment: you might have missed " how to make the lines from the two sources distinguishable" part of the question. `subprocess.STDOUT` leaves no way to distinguish stdout/err.

Comment: Still +1 as this is a useful thing to know on this topic

Comment: Yup. Not what OP asked, but what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 14):

I found myself having to tackle this problem recently, and it took a while to get something I felt worked correctly in most cases, so here it is! (It also has the nice side effect of processing the output via a python logger, which I've noticed is another common question here on Stackoverflow).

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import logging
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout,level=logging.INFO)
logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO+2,'STDERR')
logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO+1,'STDOUT')
logger = logging.getLogger('root')

pobj = subprocess.Popen(['python','-c','print 42;bargle'], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

def logstream(stream,loggercb):
    while True:
        out = stream.readline()
        if out:
            loggercb(out.rstrip())       
        else:
            break

stdout_thread = Thread(target=logstream,
    args=(pobj.stdout,lambda s: logger.log(logging.INFO+1,s)))

stderr_thread = Thread(target=logstream,
    args=(pobj.stderr,lambda s: logger.log(logging.INFO+2,s)))

stdout_thread.start()
stderr_thread.start()

while stdout_thread.isAlive() and stderr_thread.isAlive():
     pass
```

Here is the output:

```
STDOUT:root:42
STDERR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
STDERR:root:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
STDERR:root:NameError: name 'bargle' is not defined
```

You can replace the subprocess call to do whatever you want, I just chose running python with a command that I knew would print to both stdout and stderr.  The key bit is reading stderr and stdout each in a separate thread. Otherwise you may be blocking on reading one while there is data ready to be read on the other.

Comment: This won't produce properly interleaved output if the child subprocess uses block-buffering when in non-interactive mode (as it usually is). [I've tried to fix it using pty](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11709034/4279)

Comment: Unlike Rojan's answer this works on windows, which is good.  Though I think `while stdout_thread.isAlive() and stderr_thread.isAlive()` is inefficient and can be replaced with `stdout_thread.join()` `stderr_thread.join()`

Comment: the `and` instruction of `stdout_thread.isAlive() and stderr_thread.isAlive()` should be replaced with a `or`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to interleave to get roughly the same order that you would if you ran the process interactively then you need to do what the shell does and poll stdin/stdout and write in the order that they poll.

Here's some code that does something along the lines of what you want - in this case sending the stdout/stderr to a logger info/error streams.

```
tsk = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

poll = select.poll()
poll.register(tsk.stdout,select.POLLIN | select.POLLHUP)
poll.register(tsk.stderr,select.POLLIN | select.POLLHUP)
pollc = 2

events = poll.poll()
while pollc > 0 and len(events) > 0:
  for event in events:
    (rfd,event) = event
    if event & select.POLLIN:
      if rfd == tsk.stdout.fileno():
        line = tsk.stdout.readline()
        if len(line) > 0:
          logger.info(line[:-1])
      if rfd == tsk.stderr.fileno():
        line = tsk.stderr.readline()
        if len(line) > 0:
          logger.error(line[:-1])
    if event & select.POLLHUP:
      poll.unregister(rfd)
      pollc = pollc - 1
    if pollc > 0: events = poll.poll()
tsk.wait()
```

Comment: You've got a copy-paste error--you always read from `tsk.stdout`.  Also, you could do `for rfd, event in events:`.  Otherwise, +1.

Comment: I ran your program (with [some modifications](http://pastebin.com/gScsiU9S)) calling [this other program](http://pastebin.com/yHGx4wWn) and the output was [this](http://pastebin.com/VkjN3T9P). Why is the output of stderr always presented first? I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: In my case the correct ordering is more important than this whole 'set-apart' thing, so it would be interesting how much variation would this polling approach introduce?

Comment: @brandizzi - i removed the two continue lines. try again. if still misordered then add "-u" to the child process.

Comment: @T.Rojan I removed the `continue`s and it did not work, but it worked when I _also_ gave `-u` to the popened Python. It is hard stuff and your answer will help me to understand it better. So, since I am not the OP, I can just upvote and hope you have your answer accepted :)

Comment: This won't produce properly interleaved output if the child subprocess uses block-buffering when in non-interactive mode (as it usually is). [I've tried to fix it using pty](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11709034/4279)

Comment: Am I right that this will not work in windows (but will on linux/mac)? I am looking to multiple subprocess output filtering on windows. I was hoping to keep it single threaded - which I'm no longer sure is possible.

Comment: It didn't work on windows for me - `select.poll()` seems to be unimplemented

Comment: @DannyStaple: if buffering is not an issue then you could use [threading (see `teed_call()` definition)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25755038/4279) or [asyncio solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25960956/4279).

Comment: This solution is wrong! If you get a poll from a stream it means there's some data available, which may be SEVERAL lines. The code is reading only the first line. This means the next lines will be read in next polls, later than expected, and at the end when the process exits, there'll be lines left to read.

Comment: @SideshowBob: You are right.  It was covered in a different Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251809/python-select-select-on-windows

Comment: @Dirbaio fixed that issue in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75939562/2576372

Answer (score 3):

At the moment all other answers don't handle buffering on the child subprocess' side if the subprocess is not a Python script that accepts `-u` flag. See ["Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?" in the pexpect documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe).

To simulate `-u` flag for some of C stdio-based (`FILE*`) programs you could try [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation).

If you ignore this then your output won't be properly interleaved and might look like:

```
stderr
stderr
...large block of stdout including parts that are printed before stderr...
```

You could try it with the following client program, notice the difference with/without `-u` flag (`['stdbuf', '-o', 'L', 'child_program']` also fixes the output):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

def tprint(msg, file=sys.stdout):
    time.sleep(.1*random.random())
    print("%s %s" % (datetime.utcnow().strftime('%S.%f'), msg), file=file)

tprint("stdout1 before stderr")
tprint("stdout2 before stderr")
for x in range(5):
    tprint('stderr%d' % x, file=sys.stderr)
tprint("stdout3 after stderr")
```

On Linux you could use [`pty`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/pty.html#example) to get the same behavior as when the subprocess runs interactively e.g., here's a modified [@T.Rojan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810231/4279):

```
import logging, os, select, subprocess, sys, pty

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()
p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=slave_fd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
with os.fdopen(master_fd) as stdout:
    poll = select.poll()
    poll.register(stdout, select.POLLIN)
    poll.register(p.stderr,select.POLLIN | select.POLLHUP)

    def cleanup(_done=[]):
        if _done: return
        _done.append(1)
        poll.unregister(p.stderr)
        p.stderr.close()
        poll.unregister(stdout)
        assert p.poll() is not None

    read_write = {stdout.fileno(): (stdout.readline, logger.info),
                  p.stderr.fileno(): (p.stderr.readline, logger.error)}
    while True:
        events = poll.poll(40) # poll with a small timeout to avoid both
                               # blocking forever and a busy loop
        if not events and p.poll() is not None:
            # no IO events and the subprocess exited
            cleanup()
            break

        for fd, event in events:
            if event & select.POLLIN: # there is something to read
                read, write = read_write[fd]
                line = read()
                if line:
                    write(line.rstrip())
            elif event & select.POLLHUP: # free resources if stderr hung up
                cleanup()
            else: # something unexpected happened
                assert 0
sys.exit(p.wait()) # return child's exit code
```

It assumes that stderr is always unbuffered/line-buffered and stdout is line-buffered in an interactive mode. Only full lines are read. The program might block if there are non-terminated lines in the output.

Comment: fails when output is too fast, e.g. `bash -c 'for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do echo out; echo err >&2; done'`

Comment: @MilaNautikus what did you expect to happen? what happens instead? What specific code, python version, OS have you used?

Comment: to make it fail, put the bash code in a separate file (`test.sh`) and use `args = ['bash', 'test.sh']`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write your own handlers, something like (not tested, I hope you catch the idea):

```
class my_buffer(object):
    def __init__(self, fileobject, prefix):
        self._fileobject = fileobject
        self.prefix = prefix
    def write(self, text):
        return self._fileobject.write('%s %s' % (self.prefix, text))
    # delegate other methods to fileobject if necessary

log_file = open('log.log', 'w')
my_out = my_buffer(log_file, 'OK:')
my_err = my_buffer(log_file, '!!!ERROR:')
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=my_out, stderr=my_err, shell=True)
```

Comment: You need to set `self.prefix`.

Comment: In my understanding Popen expects file descriptors as _stdout_ and _stdin_, and is not very liberal about this. Am I wrong?

Comment: "Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None."
So, I suggest giving it a so-called file-like object

Comment: @beemtree, a file-like object just means an object that has `write`, `read` and `seek` methods. However, because the `my_buffer` object will never be read or seeked, Guard needs to implement `write`.

Comment: this won't work. `subprocess` operates on `fd` level i.e., `.write()` method won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on T.Rojan's code so it works when stderr or stdout receive content longer than one line.

```
# Use subprocess.Popen to run the code in the temporary file and capture stdout and stderr
process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, temp_file.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# Capture the output while the process is running by polling the stdout and stderr pipes and reading from them
poll = select.poll()
poll.register(process.stdout,select.POLLIN | select.POLLHUP)
poll.register(process.stderr,select.POLLIN | select.POLLHUP)
pollc = 2

events = poll.poll()
while pollc > 0 and len(events) > 0:
  for event in events:
    (rfd, event) = event
    if event & select.POLLIN:
      if rfd == process.stdout.fileno():
        while True:
          line = process.stdout.readline()
          if len(line) == 0:
            break
          # We don't want to print the newline character at the end of the line so we slice it off
          logger.info(line[:-1].decode('utf-8'))
      if rfd == process.stderr.fileno():
        while True:
          line = process.stderr.readline()
          if len(line) == 0:
            break
          logger.error(line[:-1].decode('utf-8'))
    if event & select.POLLHUP:
      poll.unregister(rfd)
      pollc = pollc - 1
  if pollc > 0:
    events = poll.poll()

process.wait()
```

However I made these classes which are far better in my opinion but go a fair bit beyond the scope of this question. You'll probably want to edit out DEBUG:

code_executor.py

```
import logging, os, select, subprocess, sys, tempfile, pty
from colorama import Fore
from definitions import DEBUG
from typing import Dict, Optional, Any, List, Tuple
import TimeoutHandler
import FirstInFirstOutIO

class CodeExecutor:
  # If live_output is True, the output of the code will be printed to stdout as it is generated.
  # If live_output is True or False you will still always have the full output string retuned in the Tuple along with the success boolean
  # max_output_size is the maximum size of the output string. Helpful to prevent excessive memory usage, and to prevent the output from being too large to send to OpenAI
  # timeout_seconds is the maximum number of seconds the code is allowed to run before it is terminated. TODO support Windows by using threading instead of signal.alarm
  def execute_code(self, code: str, live_output: bool= True, max_output_size: int = 1000, timeout_seconds: int = 10) -> Tuple[bool, str]:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # Setup the handler with a FirstInFirstOutIO object
    log_capture_string = FirstInFirstOutIO(max_output_size)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_capture_string)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    success = True

    # Create a temporary file to store the provided code
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False, suffix='.py') as temp_file:
      temp_file.write(code)
      temp_file.flush()
    try:
      with TimeoutHandler(timeout_seconds):
        master, slave = pty.openpty()
        # Use subprocess.Popen to run the code in the temporary file and capture stdout and stderr
        process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, temp_file.name], stdout=slave, stderr=slave, universal_newlines=True)
        os.close(slave)
        timeout = 0.1  # A small timeout value for os.read
        while True:
          rlist, _, _ = select.select([master], [], [], timeout)
          if rlist:
            data = os.read(master, 1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
              break
            for line in data.splitlines():
              if live_output:
                print(line)
              logger.info(line)
          if not process.poll() is None:
            break

    except TimeoutError:
      process.kill()
      # Handle timeout errors by appending a timeout error message to the logger and setting success to false
      message=f"Provided code took too long to finish execution. TimeoutError: Timeout after {timeout_seconds} seconds."
      logger.error(message)
      if live_output:
        print(message)
      success = False
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
      # Handle errors in the subprocess by appending the error message to the logger and setting success to false
      message=f"Error executing code: {str(e)}"
      logger.error(message)
      if live_output:
        print(message)
      success = False
    finally:
      # Remove the temporary file after execution
      os.remove(temp_file.name)
      output_string = log_capture_string.getvalue()
      log_capture_string.close()
      logger.removeHandler(handler) # Just being explicit here
      if DEBUG:
        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW} Would you like to see the output of the code? (y/n){Fore.RESET}")
        if input().lower() == 'y':
          print(output_string)
      return success, output_string
```

first_in_first_out_io.py

```
import io, collections

class FirstInFirstOutIO(io.TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, size, *args):
        self.maxsize = size
        io.TextIOBase.__init__(self, *args)
        self.deque = collections.deque()
    def getvalue(self):
        return ''.join(self.deque)
    def write(self, x):
        self.deque.append(x)
        self.shrink()
    def shrink(self):
        if self.maxsize is None:
            return
        size = sum(len(x) for x in self.deque)
        while size > self.maxsize:
            x = self.deque.popleft()
            size -= len(x)
```

timeout_handler.py

```
import signal
import sys

# This is a context manager that will raise a TimeoutError if the code inside 
# the context manager takes longer than the given number of seconds
class TimeoutHandler:
  def __init__(self, seconds: int):
    self.seconds = seconds

  def __enter__(self):
    if sys.platform == "win32":
      # Windows does not support SIGALRM, so skip the timeout handling
      return self
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle_timeout)
    signal.alarm(self.seconds)
    return self

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    if sys.platform != "win32":
      signal.alarm(0)

  def handle_timeout(self, signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutError(f"Timeout after {self.seconds} seconds.")
```

Comment: Nice work. Can't believe this topic is still going

Answer (score 0):

You may write the stdout/err to a file after the command execution.
In the example below I use pickling so I am sure I will be able to read without any particular parsing to differentiate between the stdout/err and at some point I could dumo the exitcode and the command itself.

```
import subprocess
import cPickle

command = 'ls -altrh'
outfile = 'log.errout'
pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()

f = open(outfile, 'w')
cPickle.dump({'out': stdout, 'err': stderr},f)
f.close()
```

Comment: the OP wants stdout/err *interleaved*.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian: Which became apperant in a comment 5 minutes after Cinquo already posted it.