# python select.select() on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, select

I'm testing UDP punching using code from [here](https://gist.github.com/koenbollen/464613). It works on Linux however reports error on Windows. Here's the code snippet where the error occurs:

```
while True:
    rfds, _, _ = select([0, sockfd], [], [])  # sockfd is a socket
    if 0 in rfds:
        data = sys.stdin.readline()
        if not data:
            break
        sockfd.sendto(data, target)
    elif sockfd in rfds:
        data, addr = sockfd.recvfrom(1024)
        sys.stdout.write(data)
```

And error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "udp_punch_client.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "udp_punch_client.py", line 50, in main
    rfds, _, _ = select([0, sockfd], [], [])
select.error: (10038, '')
```

I know this error has some thing to do with the `select` implementation on Windows, and everyone quote this:

> **Note** File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On
>   Windows, the underlying select() function is provided by the WinSock
>   library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate
>   from WinSock.

So I got two questions:

1. What does `0` in `[0, sockfd]` mean? Is this some sort often-used technique?
2. If `select` only works with `socket` on Windows, How to make the code Windows compatible?

Thank you.

Comment: `0` is the `fd` for `stdin`. [File Descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)

Comment: @tmr232 any idea how to modify the code?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Alright

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, `select` will not help you to process `stdin` and network events in one thread, as `select` can't work with streams on Windows. What you need is a way to read `stdin` without blocking. You may use:

1. An extra thread for `stdin`. That should work fine and be the easiest way to do the job. Python threads support is quite ok if what you need is just waiting for I/O events.
2. A [greenlet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet)-like mechanism like in [gevent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent) that patches threads support and most of I/O functions of the standard library to prevent them from blocking the greenlets. There also are libraries like `twisted` (see the comments) that offer non-blocking file I/O. This way is the most consistent one, but it should require to write the whole application using a style that matches your framework (`twisted` or `gevent`, the difference is not significant). However, I suspect `twisted` wrappers are not capable of async input from `stdin` on Windows (quite sure they can do that on *nix, as probably they use the same `select`).
3. Some other trick. However, most of the possible tricks are rather ugly.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soon as I get it to work.

Comment: +1 threads are probably the easiest route on Windows. There is also `twisted`, `asyncio` (tulip)

Comment: Should look at `asyncio`, thanks. As for `twisted`, it's an excellent library (I generally use `twisted` or `gevent` and like both). And yes, it has wrappers for file-like object. I really think that using a  framework of such sort is the best solution. However, it is not just about a minor fix to existing code.

Comment: Oops. Twisted wrapper seem to work with POSIX file descriptors. Probably it may not be capable of waiting for stdin on Windows.

Comment: The corresponding twisted bug is 7 years old, here's [the patch](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/attachment/ticket/2157/t-internet-t-test.2.patch). And here's [asyncio and stdio recipe](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-tulip/6tRswyRhwE4/l2rHgkzOc0oJ)

Answer (score 7):

As the answer suggests, I create another thread to handle input stream and it works.
Here's the modified code:

```
sock_send = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def send_msg(sock):
    while True:
        data = sys.stdin.readline()
        sock.sendto(data, target)

def recv_msg(sock):
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        sys.stdout.write(data)

Thread(target=send_msg, args=(sock_send,)).start()  
Thread(target=recv_msg, args=(sockfd,)).start()
```