# p.communicate() doesn't send the input right away

Tags: python, powershell

I have a Python script that will do

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "DirectoryOfA.batFile], stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)
```

I also have

```
while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    if now[4] == 0:
        p.communicate(input = b'something')[0]
    output = str(p.stdout.readline())
    print(output)
```

so I can see the outputs that come out of it. inside the while loop I have an `if` statement that if it's true, I want it to send an input to the powershell but it doesn't actually send the input until another output is sent and I'm not sure why.

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't send the input?

Comment: What do you intend to achieve by `if now[4] == 0`? Have you checked whether this condition is true when you expect it to?

Comment: the condition is true its just an example condition i have set, and it doesnt send the input because i can physically see that it doesnt do it, until another output is recieved, then it will send the input

Comment: Well `readline()` blocks while it waits for something to read, and only then does the code loop around to the next `communicate()`.

Comment: ok that makes sense, how would i go about making it not wait if thats possible

Comment: Maybe implement with asyncio - [https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html)

Comment: Or concurrent.futures - https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: Does [Python: How to read stdout of subprocess in a nonblocking way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476841/python-how-to-read-stdout-of-subprocess-in-a-nonblocking-way) answer your question?

Comment: i figured that part out with threading, now im having another issue with p.communicate closing stdout and i dont want that

Comment: `communicate` waits for end of program which closes `stdout`. If you want to run process all time then you have to use `p.stdin` and `p.stdout` instead of `communicate` - ie. `p.stdin.write( b'something' + b'\n' )` - sometimes it may need also `p.stdin.flush()`