# How to get input from user with non- blocking function in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, pycharm, user-input

I  tried a lot to find how to use msvcrt.kbhit() but all I write, it works wrong...
I tried:

```
while True:
    msg = ''
    print("Waiting for your message.\n")
    time.sleep(1)  # I tried with and without this line...  
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        msg = msvcrt.getch().decode()
        print(msg, end='', flush=True)
        if ord(msg) == 13:  # Client enter 'ENTER'
            break
```

In this line: `print(msg, end='', flush=True)` `end` and `flush` are red
???

(Other than that, all the code works great!
When I used INPUT - everything worked fine...)

Comment: So, does your code work or not?

Comment: No, of course.
Otherwise, why am I asking?

Comment: Why do you say: `"all the code works great"`?

Comment: Attention:
I wrote: "When I used INPUT - everything worked fine..."
This function (msvcrt.kbhit()) makes problem but I must use it...
I realy don't know what to do...

Comment: That was not clear in your question. So, the code that you posted doesn't work. But how doesn't it work? Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.
I will explain the errors: if I try to enter an input - after only one letter the input is sent to the server - which of course results in an invalid input...
Or the output I enter is printed on the screen countless times in an endless loop...
I would appreciate to get an example of code that replaces the input() function, but non-blocking...
Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python select.select() on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251809/python-select-select-on-windows)

Comment: your `while True` is a "hot loop", polling for user input as fast as it possibly can.  any time you have to govern that -or any - behavior with `sleep` it's an indication that you're doing it wrong.  This would be trivial in any normal operating system by using `select` but windows has to be weird and not support that

Comment: So, what do you mean by non-blocking? If I wrap up some code like yours that has a `while` loop into a function, the function is still seen as blocking. What is your code doing that requires something else to be non-blocking? Could your code poll something else at the same time?

Comment: Non-blocking, I mean not input() function. I use msvcrt.kbhit() to enable some requests from clients to server. Otherwise the server will wait for the client until he type something.
Do you understand?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Any other function is not the `input()` function. I can write a function which emulates `input()` by using the `msvcrt.kbhit` as you suggest, but I don't know how that would help you.

Comment: Ok, I'd appreciate  try your suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this code is a 'replacement' for `input()`, but uses `msvcrt`.

```py
import msvcrt
import time

def nonblocking_input(prompt):
    print(prompt, end='', flush=True)
    msg = ''
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            ch = msvcrt.getch().decode()
            if ord(ch) == 13:
                print()
                return msg
            print(ch, end='', flush=True)
            msg += ch
        time.sleep(0.05)

def main():
    msg = nonblocking_input('Waiting for your message: ')
    print(f'Ok, got:"{msg}"')

main()
```

I used `time.sleep(0.05)` to reduce the average cpu load.

I tested this code with `python` at the windows `cmd` prompt because `pycharm` seems to have a problem with `msvcrt`