# Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'm running a script via Python's subprocess module. Currently I use:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('/path/to/script', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.communicate()
```

I then print the result to the stdout. This is all fine but as the script takes a long time to complete, I wanted real time output from the script to stdout as well. The reason I pipe the output is because I want to parse it.

Comment: related: [Python: read streaming input from `subprocess.communicate()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279)

Comment: related: [Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279)

Comment: You might try using subprocess.call( ['/path/to/script'] ) if you don't need access to all the lower-level options of Popen.  Output should stream to stdout by default.

Comment: @Lukeclh: `call('/path/to/script')` will show the output but you won't be able to capture it at the same time (to parse it later as OP asks).

Comment: related: [Subprocess.Popen: cloning stdout and stderr both to terminal and variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17190221/4279)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To save subprocess' stdout to a variable for further processing and to [display it while the child process is running as it arrives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from io import StringIO
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen('/path/to/script', stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
           universal_newlines=True) as p, StringIO() as buf:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
        buf.write(line)
    output = buf.getvalue()
rc = p.returncode
```

To save both subprocess's stdout and stderr is more complex because you should [consume both streams concurrently to avoid a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279):

```
stdout_buf, stderr_buf = StringIO(), StringIO()
rc =  teed_call('/path/to/script', stdout=stdout_buf, stderr=stderr_buf,
                universal_newlines=True)
output = stdout_buf.getvalue()
...
```

where [`teed_call()` is define here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4985080/4279).

---

**Update:** here's [a simpler `asyncio` version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25960956/4279).

---

<sup>Old version:</sup>

Here's a single-threaded solution based on [`child_process.py` example from `tulip`](https://code.google.com/p/tulip/source/browse/examples/child_process.py):

```
import asyncio
import sys
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE

@asyncio.coroutine
def read_and_display(*cmd):
    """Read cmd's stdout, stderr while displaying them as they arrive."""
    # start process
    process = yield from asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd,
            stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    # read child's stdout/stderr concurrently
    stdout, stderr = [], [] # stderr, stdout buffers
    tasks = {
        asyncio.Task(process.stdout.readline()): (
            stdout, process.stdout, sys.stdout.buffer),
        asyncio.Task(process.stderr.readline()): (
            stderr, process.stderr, sys.stderr.buffer)}
    while tasks:
        done, pending = yield from asyncio.wait(tasks,
                return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        assert done
        for future in done:
            buf, stream, display = tasks.pop(future)
            line = future.result()
            if line: # not EOF
                buf.append(line)    # save for later
                display.write(line) # display in terminal
                # schedule to read the next line
                tasks[asyncio.Task(stream.readline())] = buf, stream, display

    # wait for the process to exit
    rc = yield from process.wait()
    return rc, b''.join(stdout), b''.join(stderr)
```

The script runs `'/path/to/script` command and reads line by line both its stdout&stderr concurrently. The lines are printed to parent's stdout/stderr correspondingly and saved as bytestrings for future processing. To run the `read_and_display()` coroutine, we need an event loop:

```
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop() # for subprocess' pipes on Windows
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    rc, *output = loop.run_until_complete(read_and_display("/path/to/script"))
    if rc:
        sys.exit("child failed with '{}' exit code".format(rc))
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`p.communicate()` waits for the subprocess to complete](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) and then returns its entire output at once.

Have you tried something like this instead, where you read the subprocess output line-by-line?

```
p = subprocess.Popen('/path/to/script', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
  # do something with this individual line
  print line
```

Comment: if the child process generates enough output to fill OS stderr pipe buffer (65K on my machine) then it hangs. You should consume `p.stderr` too -- concurrently. Due to the read-ahead bug, `for line in p.stdout` will print in bursts. You could use `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')` instead. `print line` will print double newlines. You could use `print line,` (note: comma), to avoid it.

Comment: Great point about consuming `stderr` too. I was assuming that a few lines of buffering wouldn't be an issue in a lengthy data stream, but that's something to consider as well.

Comment: *"the script takes a long time to complete"* -- it means that if the script writes progress to stderr then it *can* stall.

Answer (score 0):

The Popen.communicate doc clearly states:

```
Note: The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

So if you need realtime output, you need to use something like this:

```
stream_p = subprocess.Popen('/path/to/script', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while stream_line in stream_p:
    #Parse it the way you want
    print stream_line
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints both stdout and stderr to the terminal as well as saving both stdout and stderr into a variable:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

with Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, text=True, bufsize=1) as p:
    output = "".join([print(buf, end="") or buf for buf in p.stdout])
```

However, depending on what exactly you're doing, this might be important to note: By using `stderr=STDOUT`, we cannot differentiate between stdout and stderr anymore and with the call to `print`, your output will always be printed to stdout, doesn't matter if it came from stdout or stderr.

For Python < 3.7 you will need to use `universal_newlines` instead of `text`.

> New in version 3.7: text was added as a more readable alias for universal_newlines.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen