# How to capture output without preventing it from output in python

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I want to run command line in python, and capture the output. I can use `subprocess.check_output`. But it will suppress the output, how can i do it without suppressing the console output?

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi I need it to output on the console, i don't want to `print` the return value, because sometimes i want to debug if subprocess is hanging

Comment: to support multiple pipes, see [Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279) (threads-based implementation + a link to an asyncio version)

Comment: related: [Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279) (the question from the [subprocess' tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["/usr/bin/nc", "-l", "9999"], stdout=PIPE)

buffer = []
line = proc.stdout.readline()
while line:
    buffer.append(line)
    print "LINE", line.strip()
    line = proc.stdout.readline()

print "buffer", ''.join(buffer)
```

Using another terminal send some text

```
nc localhost 9999
# type something.  the text should appear from the python code
```

Break the nc, and you get the output in `buffer` as well

Comment: @demonguy: or more succinctly: [`for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''): print line,` (note: comma at the end)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279). Unrelated: you could use `socket` module instead of `nc` command.

Comment: But i see document like this `Warning Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.` how to avoid it?

Comment: @demonguy: it doesn't apply if all you need is to read a *single* pipe. Look at the links I've provided in the comments that use threads, async.io to consume *multiple* pipes, to avoid the deadlock.