# How to run Python subprocess and stream but also filter stdout and stderr?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a server-like app I want to run from Python. It never stops until user interrupts it. I want to continuously redirect both stdout and stderr to parent when the app runs. Lucklily, that's exactly what `subprocess.run` does.

Shell:

```
$ my-app
1
2
3
...
```

`wrapper.py`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['my-app'])
```

Executing `wrapper.py`:

```
$ python wrapper.py
1
2
3
...
```

I believe it's thanks to the fact that `subprocess.run` inherits stdout and stderr file descriptiors from the parent process. Good.

But now I need to do something when the app outputs particular line. Imagine I want to run arbitrary Python code when the output line will contain `4`:

```
$ python wrapper.py
1
2
3
4   <-- here I want to do something
...
```

Or I want to remove some lines from the output:

```
$ python wrapper.py   <-- allowed only odd numbers
1
3
...
```

I thought I could have a filtering function which I'll just hook somehow into the `subprocess.run` and it will get called with every line of the output, regardless whether it's stdout or stderr:

```
def filter_fn(line):
    if line ...:
        return line.replace(...
    ...
```

But how to achieve this? How to hook such or similar function into the `subprocess.run` call?

---

**Note:** I can't use the [`sh`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) library as it has zero support for Windows.

Comment: look at [Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279) question mentioned in the [subprocess' tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to be able to process stdout or stderr for a subprocess, just pass `subprocess.PIPE` for the parameter `stdout` (resp. `stderr`). You can then access the output stream from the subprocess as `proc.stdout`, by default as a byte stream, but you can get it as strings with `universal_newlines = True`. Example:

```
import subprocess
app = subprocess.Popen(['my-app'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
for line in app.stdout:
    if line.strip() == '4':
        # special processing
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

What you must pay attention, is that to be able to process output as soon as it is written by the subprocess, the subprocess must flush output after each line. By default, stdout is line buffered when directed to a terminal - each line is printed on the newline - but is *size buffered*  when directed to a file or pipe, meaning that it is flushed only every 8k or 16k characters.

In that case, whatever you do on caller size, you will only get stdout when the program is finished.

Comment: @HonzaJavorek: exactly the same, add param `stderr = subprocess.PIPE` and process `app.stderr`

Comment: You can also call `subprocess.run(['my-app'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` to send them both down the same handle, meaning that when you loop over `line in app.stdout` you'll get all the output in order as your terminal would display it. Note that this means you won't be able to handle STDOUT and STERR differently.

Comment: And can I handle them separately at the same time?

Comment: @HonzaJavorek, sorry, I don't understand that question. How do you want to handle them separately and simultaneously?

Comment: In the right order, but being able to tell where it come from.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give you a good answer for that. I'm not sure at all how subprocess works on Windows, but because of how subprocess works on Linux, once you've started that sub you either send them both down the same pipe, at which point you can't tell which is which, or you separate the pipes but lose information about which text appeared first. I'd be surprised if Windows was significantly different.

Comment: @ymbirtt: it is exactly the same in Windows.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Also, look at the comment by J.F. Sebastian under my original question. There's solution for separated processing of stdout and stderr, using asyncio etc.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this code will do it.  The previous answer does not address reading from two streams at the same time which requires asyncio.  Otherwise the other answer could work for filtering stdout and then doing stderr after stdout.

This is python 3.8 which has more descriptive method names for asyncio.

Update 2021-Aug-25: Using asyncio.run and asyncio.gather as higher level, easier to understand functions rather than manipulating the asyncio loop directly.

```
import sys
import asyncio


async def output_filter(input_stream, output_stream):
    while not input_stream.at_eof():
        output = await input_stream.readline()
        if not output.startswith(b"filtered"):
            output_stream.buffer.write(output)
            output_stream.flush()


async def run_command(command):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    await asyncio.gather(
        output_filter(process.stderr, sys.stderr),
        output_filter(process.stdout, sys.stdout),
    )
    # process.communicate() will have no data to read but will close the
    # pipes that are implemented in C, whereas process.wait() will not
    await process.communicate()


def main():
    asyncio.run(run_command(["python", "sample_process.py"]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```