# Python - subprocess Popen() get both live stdout and stderr

Tags: python

Following: [live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command).

I would like to run a process with `subprocess.Popen()` and get both live STDOUT and STDERR. The problem is that if I do `readline` on one of them, it will block, and I won't be able to `readline` the other. I also don't want to unite them to one PIPE.

Is there a simple way to do it without using 2 threads per process?

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18423003/2415524)? There is a description of what to do when you need two or more pipes and how to avoid deadlock. There is also a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command#comment40948811_18423003) on this answer that links to "concrete code examples". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755038/2415524) is probably the most relevant example...?

Comment: After a brief look at the linked examples, I think it has to be multiple threads per process. If I understand correctly, you want two live IO streams, so you have to consume them both asynchronously to avoid deadlock.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks. I'll read that answer and the links.