# How to write "subprocess.run" results to a log file without using "shell=True"?

Tags: python, subprocess, mpi4py

Currently, I am using the following format to write the run results to a log file.

`p = subprocess.run(["mpiexec -n 2 ./executor >log"],shell=True)`

Could anyone tell me how to avoid using the "shell=True" while I can write a log file?

Thank you.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750468/displaying-subprocess-output-to-stdout-and-redirecting-it ?

Comment: @ewong, that question is distinct because it's trying to redirect to a file *while also getting a live stream*; the OP here doesn't require that live stream (and neither does the duplicate I closed the question with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the arguments yourself, open the file yourself, and pass the open file to `run` to make it send the output there:

```
with open('log', 'wb') as outfile:
    p = subprocess.run(['mpiexec', '-n', '2', './executor'], stdout=outfile)
```