# How to read gradle build progress from it's output?

Tags: python, gradle, subprocess, stdout

I execute gradle with python subprocess:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["./gradlew", "assemble", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, )
```

Then I run two threads which read stdout and stderr:

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def run(self):
        while True:
            line = self.stream.readline()
            if line is not None and len(line) > 0:
                // process line
            else:
               break
```

I read log correct, but I can't read output like:

```
> Building 53% > :project:assemble
```

I tried replace `readline` with `read`, but it not helped.

If I execute:

```
./gradlew assemble | hd
```

I not see build progress in `hd`.

Is some solution for read this progress?

Comment: show your thread code

Comment: I updated question. But it is not important, becouse with `hd` I can't read its too.

Comment: what output do you get running it from a shell?

Comment: In shell:
`:ui:compileDebugAidl

:ui:compileDebugRenderscript

:ui:generateDebugBuildConfig

:ui:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

:ui:mergeDebugAssets

:ui:generateDebugResValues

:ui:generateDebugResources

> Building 64% > :ui:mergeDebugResources`

In python all except last line. PS: Can't format comment.

Comment: so all except `ui:generateDebugResources > Building 64% > :ui:mergeDebugResources`?

Comment: a program such as `gradlew` may change how it behaves depending on whether its stdout is a tty. [Provide it a pty, to get progress info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31953436/4279)