# Python subprocess capture stdout race condition

Tags: python, multithreading, pipe, subprocess, race-condition

When starting a process with POpen I want to capture the stderr and stdout pipes.  My code works but has a race condition between the process being executed and the stream being wrapped.  This manifests itself by some stdout bleed into the console before being wrapped when the scheduler returns to the Python program.

```
# Start process.
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, env=context, cwd=cwd,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE if capture_out else subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE if capture_err else subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stdin=None)

# Wrap streams.
out_stream = NonBlockingStreamReader(proc.stdout) if capture_out else None
err_stream = NonBlockingStreamReader(proc.stderr) if capture_err else None
```

How can I wrap the streams before passing them into `subprocess.Popen`?

Answer (score 1):

> This manifests itself by some stdout bleed into the console before being wrapped when the scheduler returns to the Python program.

There is no race.

`stdout` is either `PIPE` or `DEVNULL` in your case. `stdout` is redirected even *before* `cmd_args` is executed (after the fork but before `exec()` is called).

If you see any output at all; it means that `cmd_args` writes outside of `stdout`, `stderr` i.e., it may write to the terminal directly. See the first reason in [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

You could use `pty` (`pexpect`), to capture such output, [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279). There could be [some issues if you want to provide multiple pseudo-ttys (to capture stdout/stderr separately)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31953436/4279).