# How to Set Ansible (Python) to unbuffer output in Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

A couple years ago I was on a project and we had Ansible playbooks running with freestyle Jenkins jobs by using `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` as an environment variable so that we can see output in realtime, it worked great, it was really useful. Then one day, it stopped working, we tried to fix it but never spent enough time figuring out "what changed" and had other priorities.

I am on another project now with the same technique, only differences are that we have newer Python, Jenkins and Ansible now. I just tried setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` again but no luck, the long running Ansible task that is using the shell module buffers all the output and displays it only after the command has returned.

I have also tried `PYTHONBUFFERED=0`, and I tried prefixing the playbook run like `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ansible-playbook ...` and also using the pipeline setting `environment` to set it and verified with a `printenv` but still no luck.

Looking for suggestions on what to try next.

How do I get Jenkins 2.233, Python 2.7.16 and Ansible 2.8.1 to not buffer the output for Ansible shell tasks?

p.s. For reference, other engineers use this technique too: e.g
 1. https://coderwall.com/p/d5zqla/unbuffered-output-with-ansible-in-jenkins
 2. https://blog.deimos.fr/2016/01/07/ansible-color-and-buffer-fix-on-jenkins/

Comment: Your environment variable is passing through a lot of different pieces, Jenkins, Python, Ansible.  I'd make sure that the environment variable is being passed down through the levels faithfully.  Find and print it at each level.

Comment: I like that idea, thanks Frank, will try soon!

Comment: Note to self: I think another good debug step is to try a freestyle job, our current jobs are pipeline jobs.

Comment: Another crumb to explore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123805/unbuffered-python-subrocess-pipe (Unbuffered Python Subrocess PIPE)

Comment: It's a good question, still very relevant 3 years later. I'm also looking how to get realtime output for long running **Pipeline Shell** steps in Jenkins console. Haven't find resolution yet...