# What is the difference between using universal_newlines=True (with bufsize=1) and using default arguments with Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am trying to read the output of a subprocess called from Python. To do this I am using Popen (because I do not think it is possible to pipe stdout if using subprocess.call).

As of now I have two ways of doing it which, in testing, seem to provide the same results.  The code is as follows:

```
with Popen(['Robocopy', source, destination, '/E', '/TEE', '/R:3', '/W:5', '/log+:log.txt'], stdout=PIPE) as Robocopy:
    for line in Robocopy.stdout:
        line = line.decode('ascii')
        message_list = [item.strip(' \t\n').replace('\r', '') for item in line.split('\t') if item != '']
        print(message_list[0], message_list[0])
    Robocopy.wait()
    returncode = Robocopy.returncode
```

and

```
with Popen(['Robocopy', source, destination, '/E', '/TEE', '/R:3', '/W:5', '/log+:log.txt'], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1) as Robocopy:
    for line in Robocopy.stdout:
        message_list = [item.strip() for item in line.split('\t') if item != '']
        print(message_list[0], message_list[2])
    Robocopy.wait()
    returncode = Robocopy.returncode
```

The first method does not include universal_newlines=True, as the documentation states this is [only usable if universal_newlines=True i.e., in a text mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess).

The second version does include universal_newlines and therefore I specify a bufsize.

Can somebody explain the difference to me?  I can't find the article but I did read about issues with an overflowing buffer causing some sort of issue and thus the importance of using `for line in stdout`.

Additionally, when looking at the output, not specifying universal_newlines makes stdout a `bytes` object - but I am not sure what difference that makes if I just decode the bytes object with `ascii` (in terms of new lines and tabs) compared universal_newlines mode.

Lastly, setting the `bufsize` to `1` makes the output "line-buffered" but I am not sure what that means.  I would appreciate an explanation about how these various elements tie together.  Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the difference between using universal_newlines=True (with bufsize=1) and using default arguments with Popen

The default values are: ***`universal_newlines=False`*** (meaning input/output is accepted as **bytes**, not Unicode strings plus the [universal newlines mode](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) handling (hence the name of the parameter. Python 3.7 provides  `text` alias that might be more intuitive here) is disabled -- you get binary data as is (unless POSIX layer on Windows messes it up) and ***`bufsize=-1`*** (meaning the streams are fully buffered -- the default buffer size is used).

`universal_newlines=True` uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` character encoding to decode bytes (that  may be different from `ascii` encoding used in your code).

If `universal_newlines=False` then `for line in Robocopy.stdout:` iterates over `b'\n'`-separated lines. If the process uses non-ascii encoding e.g., UTF-16 for its output then even if `os.linesep == '\n'` on your system; you may get a wrong result. If you want to consume text lines, use the text mode: pass `universal_newlines=True` or use `io.TextIOWrapper(process.stdout)` explicitly.

> The second version does include universal_newlines and therefore I specify a bufsize.

In general, It is not necessary to specify `bufsize` if you use `universal_newlines` (you may but it is not required). And you don't need to specify `bufsize` in your case. `bufsize=1` enables line-bufferred mode (the input buffer is flushed automatically on newlines if you would write to `process.stdin`) otherwise it is equivalent to the default `bufsize=-1`.

Comment: So the default value of `bufsize=-1` seems like it could cause an issue.  Fully buffering the stream could cause some sort of blocking correct?

And if it is not specified (in universal_newlines mode) again don't I create the possibility of blocking because of a full buffer?

Comment: @Startec: no. There is no blocking issue here (regardless of `universal_newlines`, `bufsize` values). Where do you get these ideas? If you have an issue with some specific code then ask the question about this specific code.

Comment: My apologies, my confusion came from the documentation for subprocess (i.e. `Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. The child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from. )`

But I now see that is for subprocess.call.

Thanks for your clear answer - it addresses my question(s)

Comment: @Startec: yes. if you don't read from `process.stdout` pipe (when `stdout=PIPE`) then the child process may block i.e., OS pipe buffer may be finite (at least on some systems) and therefore as soon as the child process fills it; it won't be able to write anymore (untill you drain the buffer by reading from your end of the pipe). Note: OS pipe buffer is **outside** your parent Python script; it has nothing to do with `bufsize` (that control the buffer **inside** the parent Python script), [look at the picture](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31953436/4279)