# subprocess.Popen() stdout and stderr handling

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I handle a process stderr?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('ll'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for i in proc.stdout:
   print(i)
```

Right now I am streaming the output but I am not sure how to properly deal with a potential error that might occur.

I wanted to use `out, err = proc.communicate()` but my `out` could be a very very very long string

Comment: How long a string are we talking? Up to several megabytes, buffering in memory is going to be easier and more performant, unless you need to consume the results as they're being generated.

Comment: @DanielPryden potentially "{owner} {permissions} {path}/{name}" multiplied by the number of hours in 4 years. I am also processing each string because I just need a substring of the string separated by `\n`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/python-read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate  proc.stdout.readline()

Comment: If you're actually getting filesystem information, don't use a subprocess for that! Use `os.listdir()` (or maybe `os.walk()` if you need subdirectories) plus `os.stat()` to collect the extra information. Not only will it save you messing about with a subprocess and parsing strings, it will also likely be faster overall.

Comment: @DanielPryden No it isn't getting filesystem information. `ll` was just a nice example. I am actually running an `HDFS -ls` command but `ll` was a good substitute that I think more people would understand and had similar output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run command and get its stdout, stderr separately in near real time like in a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926470/run-command-and-get-its-stdout-stderr-separately-in-near-real-time-like-in-a-te)

Answer (score 1):

If you know what error messages to expect, then one answer is to pass `subprocess.STDOUT` to the `stderr` argument of `Popen`, so that your stderr messages are in the stdout stream:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('ll'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for i in proc.stdout:
   print(i)
   # check for error message strings and do something with them
```

Or if you don't care about the stdout messages then just iterate over stderr instead:

```
dnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
proc = subprocess.Popen('ll'.split(), stdout=dnull, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for i in proc.stderr:
   print(i)
   # check for error message strings and do something with them
```