# Capture output as a tty in python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, tty

I have a executable which requires a tty (as stdin and stderr), and want to be able to test it.
I want to input stdin, and  capture the output of stdout and stderr, here's an example script:

```
# test.py
import sys
print("stdin: {}".format(sys.stdin.isatty()))
print("stdout: {}".format(sys.stdout.isatty()))
print("stderr: {}".format(sys.stderr.isatty()))
sys.stdout.flush()
line = sys.stdin.readline()
sys.stderr.write("read from stdin: {}".format(line))
sys.stderr.flush()
```

I can run this without tty, but that gets caught by [`.isatty`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.isatty) and each return False:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(b"abc\n")
print(p.communicate())
# (b'stdin: False\nstdout: False\nstderr: False\n', b'read from stdin: abc\n')
```

I want to capture the stdout and stderr and have all three return True - as a tty.

I can use [`pty`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html) to make a tty stdin:

```
import subprocess
m, s = pty.openpty()
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py"], stdin=s, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdin = os.fdopen(m, 'wb', 0)
os.close(s)
stdin.write(b"abc\n")
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
stdin.close()
print((stdout, stderr))
# (b'stdin: True\nstdout: False\nstderr: False\n', b'read from stdin: abc\n')
```

---

I've tried a bunch of permutations to make stdout and stderr tty to no avail.
The output I want here is:

```
(b'stdin: True\nstdout: True\nstderr: True\n', b'read from stdin: abc\n')
```

Comment: I haven't tested yet but, what about `stdin=s, stdout=s, stderr=s`?

Comment: @Sraw That doesn't capture the output of either stdout or stderr. But there may well be a solution using that...

Comment: @Sraw my gut feeling is that this needs 3 `pty.openpty()` pairs, one for each stdin/stdout/stderr and to be written to, read and closed in a specific order. I have tried many permutations to no avail.

Comment: @unutbu could you paste this as an answer? I am struggling to see it. Perhaps I've not had enough coffee...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below is based on jfs' answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/190597) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31953436/190597), plus your idea of using 3 pseudo-terminals to distinguish stdout, stderr and stdin (though note there is a [cryptic warning](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/7a4e29655362c86bd3b71c3122a24709b9bcbb10/sh.py#L1194) that something may go wrong (such as a possibly truncated stderr on OSX?) by doing so).

Also note that, as of Python 3.10, the docs say `pty` is [tested on Linux, macOS, and FreeBSD](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pty.html), though it is "supposed to work" for other POSIX platforms:

```
import errno
import os
import pty
import select
import subprocess

def tty_capture(cmd, bytes_input):
    """Capture the output of cmd with bytes_input to stdin,
    with stdin, stdout and stderr as TTYs.

    Based on Andy Hayden's gist:
    https://gist.github.com/hayd/4f46a68fc697ba8888a7b517a414583e
    """
    mo, so = pty.openpty()  # provide tty to enable line-buffering
    me, se = pty.openpty()  
    mi, si = pty.openpty()  

    p = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        bufsize=1, stdin=si, stdout=so, stderr=se, 
        close_fds=True)
    for fd in [so, se, si]:
        os.close(fd)
    os.write(mi, bytes_input)

    timeout = 0.04  # seconds
    readable = [mo, me]
    result = {mo: b'', me: b''}
    try:
        while readable:
            ready, _, _ = select.select(readable, [], [], timeout)
            for fd in ready:
                try:
                    data = os.read(fd, 512)
                except OSError as e:
                    if e.errno != errno.EIO:
                        raise
                    # EIO means EOF on some systems
                    readable.remove(fd)
                else:
                    if not data: # EOF
                        readable.remove(fd)
                    result[fd] += data

    finally:
        for fd in [mo, me, mi]:
            os.close(fd)
        if p.poll() is None:
            p.kill()
        p.wait()

    return result[mo], result[me]

out, err = tty_capture(["python", "test.py"], b"abc\n")
print((out, err))
```

yields

```
(b'stdin: True\r\nstdout: True\r\nstderr: True\r\n', b'read from stdin: abc\r\n')
```

Comment: Note: This has worked for me on OSX... I guess it's just "not been tested" by the python core team.

Comment: I know that this is very old but it doesn't work on Windows because `pty` imports `tty` which imports `termios` and there is no `termios` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a `readline` iterator (plus graceful shutdown) version of @unutbu's answer:

```py
import errno
import os
import pty
import signal
import subprocess


def subprocess_tty(cmd, encoding="utf-8", timeout=10, **kwargs):
    """`subprocess.Popen` yielding stdout lines acting as a TTY"""
    m, s = pty.openpty()
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=s, stderr=s, **kwargs)
    os.close(s)

    try:
        for line in open(m, encoding=encoding):
            if not line:  # EOF
                break
            yield line
    except OSError as e:
        if errno.EIO != e.errno:  # EIO also means EOF
            raise
    finally:
        if p.poll() is None:
            p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
            try:
                p.wait(timeout)
            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                p.terminate()
                try:
                    p.wait(timeout)
                except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                    p.kill()
        p.wait()
```

Example usage:

```py
import textwrap

for line in subprocess_tty(
    [
        "python",
        "-c",
        textwrap.dedent(
            """\
            import sys
            print(sys.stdin.isatty())
            print(sys.stdout.isatty())
            print(sys.stderr.isatty())
            """
        ),
    ]
):
    print(f"{line!r}")
```