How can I redirect stdout and stderr of subprocess in python to same file without losing the order
I have a simple script to mimic a program writing to stdout and stderr streams interleaved.
import sys
import time

for i in range(5):
    print(int(time.time()), "This is Stdout")
    print(int(time.time()), "Stderr", file=sys.stderr)
    time.sleep(1)

When I run such a program with Python subprocess.Popen I am losing the order of stderr and stdout.
import subprocess

file = open('./stdout1.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=file)

Output
1720517080 Stderr
1720517081 Stderr
1720517082 Stderr
1720517083 Stderr
1720517084 Stderr
1720517080 This is Stdout
1720517081 This is Stdout
1720517082 This is Stdout
1720517083 This is Stdout
1720517084 This is Stdout

I understand that the stderr gets flushed quicker or something of that sort, but how do I preserve the order?
I also tried using subprocess.STDOUT for stderr and played with text and bufsize arguments with no luck. Also tried adding buffering to the file handle. The output is identical in all cases.
Here is the full program
import subprocess

file = open('./stdout1.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=file)
file = open('./stdout2.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=file, text=True, bufsize=0)
file = open('./stdout3.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=file, text=True, bufsize=1)
file = open('./stdout4.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
file = open('./stdout5.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True, bufsize=0)
file = open('./stdout6.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True, bufsize=1)

file = open('./stdout1b.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8', buffering=1) ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=file)
file = open('./stdout2b.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8', buffering=1) ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=file, text=True, bufsize=0)
file = open('./stdout3b.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8', buffering=1) ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=file, text=True, bufsize=1)
file = open('./stdout4b.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8', buffering=1) ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
file = open('./stdout5b.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8', buffering=1) ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True, bufsize=0)
file = open('./stdout6b.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8', buffering=1) ; subprocess.Popen('./stderrout.py', stdout=file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True, bufsize=1)

Is there a way to redirect both streams to the same file without losing the order?
If not what is the significance of bufsize argument?

Try adding flush=True to prints to stdout

actual program is not in my control, first program is just to mimic actual program, so I can't add flush

Or run your subprocess with python -u …

This happens because Python's stdout only has line-buffering when connected to a terminal (TTY), probably as a performance/interactivity tradeoff.
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdout.line_buffering)'
True
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdout.line_buffering)' | cat
False

Meanwhile, stderr is always line-buffered:
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stderr.line_buffering)'
True
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stderr.line_buffering)' | cat
True

Therefore, the unwanted buffering is in the writer, not the reader, and why bufsize wasn't helping.
Solution 1: redirect stdout to a fake terminal
So to read the lines interleaved, you have to open Popen's stdout as a TTY file-descriptor using pty. Borrowing heavily from another answer:
import errno
import os
import pty
import signal
import subprocess

# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/77387332/252218
def subprocess_tty(cmd, encoding="utf-8", timeout=10, **kwargs):
    """`subprocess.Popen` yielding stdout lines acting as a TTY"""
    m, s = pty.openpty()
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=s, stderr=s, **kwargs)
    os.close(s)

    try:
        for line in open(m, encoding=encoding):
            if not line:  # EOF
                break
            yield line
    except OSError as e:
        if errno.EIO != e.errno:  # EIO also means EOF
            raise
    finally:
        if p.poll() is None:
            p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
            try:
                p.wait(timeout)
            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                p.terminate()
                try:
                    p.wait(timeout)
                except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                    p.kill()
        p.wait()

# Run the writer command, and print all stdout and stderr lines interleaved.
for line in subprocess_tty(['python3', 'stderrout.py']):
    print(line, end='')

Output:
1720520529 This is Stdout
1720520529 Stderr
1720520530 This is Stdout
1720520530 Stderr
1720520531 This is Stdout
1720520531 Stderr
1720520532 This is Stdout
1720520532 Stderr
1720520533 This is Stdout
1720520533 Stderr


Solution 2: force stderr to be unbuffered
Alternatively, you can make both stdout and stderr unbuffered. This will be slower, especially when writing many small strings. On the other hand, it's a much easier solution, just add -u:
import subprocess

file = open('./stdout1.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-u', './stderrout.py'], stdout=file, stderr=file)

