# How to run a non ending process via subprocess and collect both STDOUT and STDERR separately

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python program which executes `subprocess.Popen`, like this;

```
process = subprocess.Popen(stand_alone_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
print "out: ", out
print "err: ", err
```

If my `stand_alone_command` will run forever, how do I get whatever `stand_alone_command` is throwing at STDOUT and STDERR so that I can log it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run command and get its stdout, stderr separately in near real time like in a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926470/run-command-and-get-its-stdout-stderr-separately-in-near-real-time-like-in-a-te)

Answer (score -1):

Try reading from stdout instead of calling `communicate()` such as..

```
import subprocess
sac = ['tail', '-f', '/var/log/syslog']
process = subprocess.Popen(sac, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while 1:
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        print(line)
```

I think you'll need to set `shell=False` but I'm on Linux and Windows is a bit different.

Comment: That will ”work” until the buffer for stderr is full and the whole thing is in a deadlock.